# Lambda expression with variable length parameters

Tags: java, lambda, variadic-functions

When i trying write in method variable length parameters`(int ...x)`, i have this problem :
"Operator '+' cannot be applied to 'int[]','int'"
i want to understand, can i use `(int ...x)` when i use lambdas, and if can, how?

```
class calculations {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        func obj = (x) -> x+1;
        int result = obj.sum(10);
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
interface func {
    int sum(int ...x);
}
```

I know that variable length parameters`(int ...x)` indicates that it will be optional and will represent an array, based on this i can add multiple parametrs, for example `func obj = (x,y,w) -> x+y+w;` but it's dont work.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, `x` isn't an `int`, but an array `int[]`. Because method `sum()` expects *varags* of `int` (i.e. all the arguments would be wrapped with an auxiliary array).

For that, reason, you're getting a compilation error.

That's how the proper implementation might look like:

```
func obj = x -> Arrays.stream(x).sum();
```

Or you can apply some operations, for instance increment each element by `1`, like you were trying in your code:

```
func obj = x -> Arrays.stream(x).map(i -> i + 1).sum();
```

**Sidenote:** interface name `func` isn't aligned with the [Language naming conventions](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html). It should start with a capital letter. Also, name `func` doesn't conveys the purpose of the interface (see [Self-documenting code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-documenting_code)).